# Как вывести данные через связь?

Tags: php, laravel

```
sql
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Damp (связь result_test)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Foreach

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 пробую
 $user->result_test->estimate
 но получаю error Property [estimate] does not exist on this collection instance. ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
$user->result_test->all()
```

и посмотрите что там будет.
И еще почитатайте документацию, что такое [коллекции](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections).